# Python and selenium: Check which of two images loaded on a given page

Tags: python, html, selenium, testing, selenium-chromedriver

At the final page of my test, there's a container which contains either a green circle for "success" or a red X for "error."

```
<img src="https://cs.cc.unc.edu/cs/campus/cache/newg/PS_CS_STATUS_ERROR_ICN_1.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Error" class="SSSIMAGECENTER">
```

I want to check which of the two elements appears and then notify myself via email. It would be great if there were a way to retreive the string src. It would also be great to maybe get the image itself, open it with urllib2 and then check if the red color of the x is present in the image?

Answer (score 1):

In Selenium, you could do something like this (this is pseudo-code)

```
if driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("img[src*='ERROR']").size > 0:
  email("It's an error")

if driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("img[src*='SUCCESS']").size > 0:
  email("It's not an error")
```

your `email()` method will contain logic for emailing.  This in particular is not selenium specific. you can more-than-likely find a nice python package that sends emails.  Additionally, this is pseudo-code to give you an idea of how to do it.  You will have to account for implicit waiting and such.